# Index for using IN clause in where condition

Tags: sql-server, indexing

My application access data from a table in SQL Server. Consider the table name is PurchaseDetail with some other columns.
The select query has below where clauses.
1. name - name has 10000 values only.
2. createdDateTime

The actual query is

```
select *
from PurchaseDetail
where name in (~2000 name)
and createdDateTime = 'someDateValue';
```

The SQL tuning advisor gave some recommendation. I tried with those recommended indexes. The performance increased a bit but not completely.

Is there any wrong in my query? or Is there any possible to change/improve my select query?
Because I didn't use IN in where clause before. My table having more than 100 million records.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Using an `IN` with a list of 2,000 values is going to be a killer. Seems like you'd be better off with a table-value parameter and a `JOIN`.

Comment: Also, if you're using `SELECT *` the only indexes that'll be useful is the `CLUSTERED INDEX`, or a `NONCLUSTERED` index that includes every single column in the table (either in the index itself, or as an `INCLUDE` column). if you don't need every column, don't return every column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case using `IN` for that much data is not good at all.
this best way is to use `INNER JOIN` instead.
It would be nicer if insert those names into a temp table and `INNER JOIN` it with your `SELECT` query.